# Python: BeautifulSoup - Accessing a element without further specification

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I get the text of that bold element?
Thanks in advance

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="graph-legend-color" 
        style="width:12px;height:11px;background- 
        color:#3366CC">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="percent">48,9 %</td>
    <td class="number">92.234</td>
    **<td>Proxy-Block Types From Download Media Type Blocklist</td>**
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you see, the bold element (`<td>`) is last `<td>` element inside the `<tr>` tag. So you select all `<td>` tags inside `<tr>` tag and get the element with index `-1` (in Python that means last index):

```
data = """
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="graph-legend-color"
        style="width:12px;height:11px;background-
        color:#3366CC">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="percent">48,9 %</td>
    <td class="number">92.234</td>
    <td>Proxy-Block Types From Download Media Type Blocklist</td>
</tr>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.select('tr > td')[-1].text)
```

Prints:

```
Proxy-Block Types From Download Media Type Blocklist
```